# Hacked ubuntu pc? Broadcast messages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, broadcast

I have a fresh ubuntu 13 os installed on my system with almost default programs installed. But whenever I shutdown my pc i got these messages.

Broadcast from root@..
(Unknown) at ...

The system is going down..

Is my pc got hacked?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

When you shutdown a PC it is normal broadcast messages to all users. A classic shutdown would be in this form "shutdown -h +90m Installing new RAM!".

That would do a few things:

1. Send a broadcast (from root) to all users (local and remotely logging in) with: Shutdown. System is going down in 90 minutes. Reason: Installing new RAM!
2. It would repeat this at intervals (e.g. at T-5 minutes, T-1 minute).
3. At some time (I think it was T+5 minutes) it would block people from remotely logging in). (equivalent to `touch /etc/nologin`)
4. It would repeat this one last time at shutdown time (System is going down NOW).

The only strange thing at your message (root@unknown.tld) is that the host name is not known. What did you set it to?